# Blank Page using gh-pages not injecting root div

Tags: reactjs, git, dom, github-pages, react-bootstrap

Hello i can not deply on github pages, and i think i tried everything. Page go blank, when i remove index.html from main folder (default path is public folder) side is showing readme file.

Full code : https://github.com/mr-krystian-stawarczyk/Porfolio

Also installing npm gh-pages does not upload gh-pages branch to github site.

It looks like root div is not injected.

json

```
{
    "name": "portfolio-project",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": false,
    "dependencies": {
        "homepage" : "https://mr-krystian-stawarczyk.github.io/Porfolio",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
        "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
        "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "emailjs-com": "^2.6.4",
        "jquery": "0.0.1-security",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-fontawesome": "^1.7.1",
        "react-hook-form": "^7.5.3",
        "react-particles-js": "^3.4.1",
        "react-popupbox": "^2.0.8",
        "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.18",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
        "react-scroll": "^1.8.2",
        "react-share": "^4.4.0",
        "react-typed": "^1.2.0",
        "react-update-popup": "^1.0.3",
        "reactjs-popup": "^2.0.4",
        "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "predeploy": "npm run build",
        "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "gh-pages": "^3.1.0"
    }
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        />

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <meta
            name="description"
            content="Web site created using create-react-app"
        />

        <title>React App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script
            src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

PLEASE HELP :(